# Flash AS3 Help detecting a loaded file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, filereference

I'm trying to load an external and local XML file to read its data, but I don't really know how to detect when the file has been loaded, I'm just able to open the broser window, 
here is what I have done
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

```
public class cargadorXML extends Sprite {


    public var cuadro:Sprite = new Sprite();
    public function cargadorXML() {


        cuadro.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
        cuadro.graphics.drawRoundRect(0,0,100,100,10);
        cuadro.graphics.endFill();
        cuadro.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,init);
        addChild(cuadro);

    }
    public function init(e:Event) {

        var file:FileReference;

        file = new FileReference();
        file.browse();
        file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,bien);

    }
    public function bien(e:Event) {
        trace("cargado");
    }
}
```

}

but no "cargado" message appears, also I don't really think the Event.COMPLETE is the correct event at all xD
could some one help me here??
thanks

Answer (score 0):

done, it's Event.SELECT instead of Event.COMPLETE